# VNC server installed or not in redhat linux - please read the lines below

Tags: linux, redhat, vnc

```
[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]# ls

VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm  VNC-Viewer-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm

[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]# rpm -e VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm
**error: package VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm is not installed**
[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]#
[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]#
[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]# rpm -ivh VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        **package realvnc-vnc-server-5.1.1.17550-1.x86_64 is already installed**
[root@cpsc-server VNCInstallable]#
```

whats wrong, how do i completely remove the VNC and install again. Also, i am not able to view the config file under `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers`

Comment: Isn't it just that -e expects a package name rather than a file name?

Comment: well, that IS a package name there i suppose. am i missing something?

Comment: Based on the output you have included it sounds like the package name is `realvnc-vnc-server-5.1.1.17550-1.x86_64` while the filename is `VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm`

Comment: Yes, thats right .. Thanks !! ..

How do i retrieve the missing `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` ?, or am i looking for it in the wrong place .. because i am on Redhat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gave the `rpm -e` command a file name. It wants a package name. Just because the file is called `VNC-Server-5.1.1-Linux-x64.rpm` doesn't mean the package is called the same thing. I can rename the file all I want, and when I install it, the package will still have the original name (in this case, `realvnc-vnc-server`, version 5.1.1.17550, release 1, with an x86_64 architecture).

Comment: Yes, absolutely, Thanks!!, i removed vnc with the package name. But how do i find the config file? isn't it supposed to be at `/etc/sysconfig/vncservers` ?

Comment: If you've remove the package, the config file may not be there any longer. The config file is probably in the payload (`rpm -ql realvnc-vnc-server` while it's installed), but might be ghosted and not show up.

Comment: If the intent is to re-install theres a greate EZ guide at http://www.1337admin.org/linux/configuring-vnc-server-the-easy-way-in-linux/